# The terminal process failed to launch: Starting directory (cwd) for mac

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I just started to setup my vscode and checked the path to my terminal but when I created a folder to save my files it says my path does not exist. Also I have run cpp code on there before and it says that my coderunner is not supported or language not defined

Comment: Could you attach a picture of the errors that helps to clarify the question? thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.